# Merge multiple data.tables and rename columns to reflect origin

Tags: r, merge, data.table

As a simplified example of my problem, say I have four `data.tables` `dt1`, ..., `dt4`, all with the same structure:

```
head(dt1)
          date          x           y
 1: 2000-10-01  0.4527087 -0.11590788
 2: 2001-10-01  0.7200252 -0.55722270
 3: 2002-10-01 -1.3804472 -1.47030087
 4: 2003-10-01 -0.1380225  2.34157766
 5: 2004-10-01 -0.9288675 -1.32993998
 6: 2005-10-01 -0.9592633  0.76316150
```

That is, they all have three columns called `date`, `x` and `y`. My desired output is a merged `data.table` (on date) with five columns: `date`, and then the `x` column from each individual table renamed to reflect its original `data.table`:

```
head(desired_output)
          date      x_dt1       x_dt2      x_dt3      x_dt4
 1: 2000-10-01  0.4527087 -0.11590788  1.1581946 -1.5159040
 2: 2001-10-01  0.7200252 -0.55722270 -1.6247254 -0.3325556
 3: 2002-10-01 -1.3804472 -1.47030087 -0.9766309 -0.2368857
 4: 2003-10-01 -0.1380225  2.34157766  1.1831091 -0.4399184
 5: 2004-10-01 -0.9288675 -1.32993998  0.8716144 -0.4086229
 6: 2005-10-01 -0.9592633  0.76316150 -0.8860816 -0.4299365
```

I assume this can be done using the `suffixes` argument of `merge.data.table` somehow. I have tried to modify `mergeDTs` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69083589/10366237) without success as yet. A solution that successfully modifies `mergeDTs` (or just using a function that could be applied to a list of of several `data.tables`) would be excellent.

I am aware of [this very slick dplyr/purrr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152352/suffixes-when-merging-more-than-two-data-frames-with-full-join) but would prefer a `data.table` solution.

---

##### Example data

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(date = seq(from = as.Date("2000-10-01"), to = as.Date("2010-10-01"), by = "years"),
                  x = rnorm(11),
                  y = rnorm(11))

dt2 <- data.table(date = seq(from = as.Date("2000-10-01"), to = as.Date("2010-10-01"), by = "years"),
                  x = rnorm(11),
                  y = rnorm(11))

dt3 <- data.table(date = seq(from = as.Date("2000-10-01"), to = as.Date("2010-10-01"), by = "years"),
                  x = rnorm(11),
                  y = rnorm(11))

dt4 <- data.table(date = seq(from = as.Date("2000-10-01"), to = as.Date("2010-10-01"), by = "years"),
                  x = rnorm(11),
                  y = rnorm(11))
```

---

#### Solution

Below I have put B. Christian Kamgang's answer into functional form (to make it easily adaptable to my real problem) and removed dependency on the new pipe (since my organisation hasn't yet upgraded):

```
merge_select <- function(on, vars, ..., suffix = "_") {
  dts <- list(...)
  names(dts) <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L], deparse)
  
  nv <- length(vars)
  ndt <- length(dts)
  
  old_cols <- split(rep(vars, ndt),
                    ceiling(seq_along(rep(vars, ndt))/nv))
  
  new_cols <- split(paste0(vars, suffix, rep(names(dts), each = nv)),
                    ceiling(seq_along(paste0(vars, 
                                             suffix, 
                                             rep(names(dts), each = nv)))/nv))
  
  sep_cols <- lapply(dts, function(x) subset(x, select = c(on, vars)))
  
  Reduce(f = function(x,y) merge(x, y, by = on), 
         Map(f = setnames, sep_cols, old_cols, new_cols))
}
```

Which in my situation translates to:

```
merge_select("date", "x", dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4)
          date      x_dt1       x_dt2       x_dt3       x_dt4
 1: 2000-10-01 -0.6365707  0.11804268 -0.01084163 -0.88127011
 2: 2001-10-01 -0.2533127 -3.16924568  0.45746415  0.69742537
 3: 2002-10-01  2.3069266 -0.82670409 -0.54236745 -1.49613384
 4: 2003-10-01  0.7075547 -0.91809007 -0.67888707 -0.26106146
 5: 2004-10-01 -0.7165651 -0.45711888 -0.83903416  1.45113260
 6: 2005-10-01  0.5703561  0.24587897  0.13862020  0.33928202
 7: 2006-10-01 -0.6258097 -0.77652389 -0.49252474 -0.80460241
 8: 2007-10-01 -0.4600565  0.55612959  0.86749410 -1.30850411
 9: 2008-10-01 -0.8841649 -0.48113848 -1.55858406  0.83076846
10: 2009-10-01 -0.6262272 -0.73618265  0.13350581  0.06640803
11: 2010-10-01  0.1406454  0.08994779  1.28450204 -1.18329081
```

This solution also works for multiple variables, eg.

```
merge_select("date", c("x","y"), dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
nms = paste0("dt", 1:4)

lapply(mget(nms), `[`, j=c("date", "x")) |> 
  Map(f=setnames, "x", paste0("x_", nms)) |> 
  Reduce(f=\(x,y) merge(x, y, by="date"))

          date      x_dt1      x_dt2      x_dt3       x_dt4
        <Date>      <num>      <num>      <num>       <num>
 1: 2000-10-01  1.5567877 -0.3579598  1.9765388 -0.76325891
 2: 2001-10-01 -0.2656003  0.6599606 -0.8085454 -0.43846379
 3: 2002-10-01 -0.3620652 -1.1952980 -0.7108491 -0.57261896
 4: 2003-10-01  2.2358663  0.3903301 -1.0370673  1.27767750
 5: 2004-10-01  0.7298361 -0.4111746 -0.5046095  0.35132983
 6: 2005-10-01 -0.2749529 -0.3080462 -1.5936609  0.49925692
 7: 2006-10-01 -0.4624282 -0.6598809 -2.0893062 -0.10963342
 8: 2007-10-01 -1.3491373  1.1325984 -0.4708666  0.15541533
 9: 2008-10-01 -1.9459169  0.3331132 -0.5091114 -0.56520321
10: 2009-10-01 -0.8994460 -0.5218689 -0.4177664  0.69639938
11: 2010-10-01  0.8663232 -1.6789679 -0.7827229 -0.05562114
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I used a modified version of this (see my edited post).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible approach accumulating the merged result in a simple `for` loop:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- dt1[, .(date, x)]

for(i in 2:4) {
  dt <- merge(dt, get(paste0("dt", i))[, .(date, x)], by = "date", suffixes = c("", paste0("_dt", i)))
}

setnames(dt, old = "x", new = "x_dt1")

head(dt)
#>          date      x_dt1      x_dt2        x_dt3      x_dt4
#> 1: 2000-10-01 -1.5035218  2.0463775 -0.120544283 -0.5662290
#> 2: 2001-10-01  0.5977386 -0.1968421 -0.840102174  1.2412272
#> 3: 2002-10-01 -0.9100557 -0.1687148 -1.738526471  1.3685767
#> 4: 2003-10-01  0.7027232  0.9009135 -0.247273205  1.3135718
#> 5: 2004-10-01  0.5269265  0.6176381 -0.007662592 -0.2928206
#> 6: 2005-10-01 -0.8350406 -0.7343245 -0.643701996  2.3068948
```

Or alternatively, accumulating the merged result with `Reduce()`:

```
Reduce(
  f = function(dt, dti) merge(dt, get(dti)[, .(date, x)], by = "date", suffixes = c("", paste0("_", dti))),
  x = paste0("dt", 1:4),
  init = dt1[, .(date, x)]
)[, x := NULL][]
```

---

Note: to get rid of the `get()` calls we can collect all data.tables in a list before merging or write a small function wrapper, e.g.

```
merge_dts <- function(...) {
  dts <- list(...)
  dt <- dts[[1]][, .(date, x)]
  for(i in seq_along(dts)[-1]) {
    dt <- merge(dt, dts[[i]][, .(date, x)], by = "date", suffixes = c("", paste0("_dt", i)))
  }
  setnames(dt, old = "x", new = "x_dt1")
  return(dt)
}

merge_dts(dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4)
```

Comment: Several great solutions, much appreciated. Ended up doing a mix of your last solution and B. Christian Kamgang’s solution (see my edited post).